Specifying custom arguments in sklear-style classes
I'm trying to implement my own, sklearn-compatible classifier in Python. To that end, I inherit from BaseEstimator and ClassifierMixin, but I also define my own arguments in the constructor.
While debugging, I noticed that invoking __repr__() interactively, in the IPython console, produces an AttributeError, claiming that my classifier lacks attributes which I specified. No such error appears when I run the file as a program. Also, the error appears only in Spyder on my Mac, but not in PyCharm on Windows.
Here is my minimal reproducible example:
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin


class MyClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
  def __repr__(self, **kwargs):
    return "In MyClassifier.__repr__() ..."

  def __init__(self, my_arg=0):
    pass


mc = MyClassifier()
# The following line produces
#     AttributeError: 'MyClassifier' object has no attribute 'my_arg'
# but only when run interactively:
mc

I also noticed that the error doesn't appear if I don't inherit from BaseEstimator. Also, the error doesn't appear if I assign my_arg to a member variable of the same name: In __init__(), substitute self.my_arg = my_arg for pass. self.my_differently_named_arg = my_arg, on the other hand, doesn't help.
So, is there some implicit contract that member variables must have the same names as the formal arguments, or is it a quirk in Spyder, or in the Python implementation on Mac, in sklearn, in PyCharm, in the Python implementation on Windows, or am I doing something wrong?
My configuration is: Spyder is 5.5.2, Python 3.9.7, IPython 8.18.1, sklearn 1.3.2, and my Mac is Intel Core i7 with Sonoma 14.4.1.

As mentioned in the documentation:

In addition, every keyword argument accepted by __init__ should correspond to an attribute on the instance. Scikit-learn relies on this to find the relevant attributes to set on an estimator when doing model selection.

P.S: Take a look at the documentation or any other resource you find on the internet, there are some other conventions that you should be aware of once developing a custom classifier. For example: There should be no logic in the __init__, not even input validation.
